# What is compiler warning CS1723 "XML comment has cref attribute 'T' that refers to a type parameter" all about?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, compiler-warnings, code-documentation

Given this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implementations represent a configuration with a specific data 
/// type <see cref="T"/> that can be used by this application.
/// </summary>
internal interface IConfiguration<T>
{
}
```

I'm getting a compiler warning [**CS1723**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1723) on `T` inside the `see cref` XML element:

> XML comment has cref attribute 'T' that refers to a type parameter

MS Docs is completely useless in this case.  Why should I care about this warning?  What is the reason for it?

Comment: I think the `<see cref="">` tags are designed to point another interface, class or other such thing. Here you are pointing to a type called 'T' which probably doesn't exist so its telling you that your documentation is wrong

Comment: <see/> denotes a link to another code entity. Where to you expect this link to point to?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To reference a type parameter, use [`<typeparamref name="T" />`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#typeparamref).

```
/// <summary>
/// Implementations represent a configuration with a specific data 
/// type <typeparamref name="T" /> that can be used by this application.
/// </summary>
internal interface IConfiguration<T>
{
}
```

Comment: See, now that's what I was looking for (not down votes)!  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

`see cref` (cross reference) is meant to point to an actual type (eg as a hyperlink in the generated docs). A type parameter doesn't make any sense in this place since it is not known beforehand what type is going to be used.

To document type parameters use

`<typeparamref name="name"/>`

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer.